# Python - iterate over many objects, extracting data from them to accumulate totals

Tags: python, for-loop, oop, object

I would like to iterate some number of objects,  pull  numbers out, and do an accumulated total. This is what I have:

```
print ('Calculating Commmissions with objects')
class SalesReps:
    count = 0
    def __init__( self , name , sales , commission) :
        self.name = name
        self.sales = sales
        self.commission = commission
        SalesReps.count += 1
    def name_performance_pay( self ) :
        return self.name
        return self.sales
        return self.commission
    
s1=SalesReps ('BAnderson', 15685.75, 1568.68)
s2=SalesReps ('GBates', 13856.80, 1385.68)
s3=SalesReps ('MBerger', 18560.44, 1437.04)
s4=SalesReps ('JCarter', 14375.86, 1437.59)
s5=SalesReps ('VChambers', 15963.45, 1596.35)
print('We have ', SalesReps.count, 'sales reps.\n')

for rep in range(1, 5):
    print(s[rep].name, s[rep].sales, s[rep].comission, '\n')
    totalSales = totalSales + s[rep].sales
    totalCommissions = totalCommissions + s[rep].commision

print ('Our total sales were ', totalSales, 'and our total commissions paid was ', totalCommissions, '.\n)
```

This is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jrw/Documents/bp.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(s[rep].name, s[rep].sales, s[rep].comission, '\n')
NameError: name 's' is not
```

Does Python have a different subscripting convention? I haven't found it.

Comment: what is ```s```?

Comment: s1 != s[rep] ..is not the same. I'd suggest putting them into an array and looping that.

Comment: Add your `SalesReps` objects to a list and then iterate over that list

Comment: `s = [s1,s2,s3,s4,s5]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You named five unrelated variables (`s1`, `s2`, `s3`, ...), you didn't make a single `list` named `s`, so you can't subscript `s` (there is no `s`). Change the code that initializes `s1` and company to make a single `list` named `s` and this would be a lot closer to working:

```
s = [SalesReps ('BAnderson', 15685.75, 1568.68),
     SalesReps ('GBates', 13856.80, 1385.68),
     SalesReps ('MBerger', 18560.44, 1437.04),
     SalesReps ('JCarter', 14375.86, 1437.59),
     SalesReps ('VChambers', 15963.45, 1596.35)]

for rep in range(len(s)):
```

would do it, though it wouldn't be Pythonic (`for i in range(len(someseq)):` is basically always the wrong way to do it). The more Pythonic approach would make the loop:

```
for rep in s:
    print(rep.name, rep.sales, rep.commission, '\n')
    totalSales += rep.sales
    totalCommissions += rep.commission
```

directly iterating the contents of the list, rather than the valid indices with repeated indexing.

Answer (score 0):

It's the modification with pythonic way.

- Use `len(s)` instead of `SalesReps.count`.
- Use `sum` instead of plus in for statement.

```py
print ('Calculating Commmissions with objects')
class SalesReps:
    def __init__( self , name , sales , commission) :
        self.name = name
        self.sales = sales
        self.commission = commission
    def name_performance_pay( self ) :
        return self.name
        return self.sales
        return self.commission
    
s=[SalesReps ('BAnderson', 15685.75, 1568.68),
   SalesReps ('GBates', 13856.80, 1385.68),
   SalesReps ('MBerger', 18560.44, 1437.04),
   SalesReps ('JCarter', 14375.86, 1437.59),
   SalesReps ('VChambers', 15963.45, 1596.35)]
print('We have ', len(s), 'sales reps.\n')

totalSales = sum(r.sales for r in s)
totalCommissions = sum(r.commission for r in s)
print ('Our total sales were ', totalSales, 'and our total commissions paid was ', totalCommissions, '.\n')
```